# NullPointer exception while passing a value from activity to Interface method and retrieve in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

After searching, finally, I find out that I should use an interface to pass a list of objects from an activity to a fragment.
before that, I made my object class Perceilable to send in as an argument to fragment, but it seems that it's not a good approach because I have to initiate my fragment for the first time without setting any argument and after my list of the object is ready I can pass it.
So now I want to send my list via Interface but I get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.x.x.Interfaces.CurrenciesSync.syncCurrencies(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
    at com.x.x.DashboardActivity$1.onResponse(DashboardActivity.java:124)
```

here is my interface file codes:

```
public interface CurrenciesSync {


public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies);

}
```

here is the way I set currencies List in DashboardActivity to syncCurrencies method:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        CurrenciesSync currenciesSync;
```

currenciesSync.syncCurrencies(currencies);
    }
And how I implement it's method :

```
public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies) {
 // using currencies here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the object:

```
    CurrenciesSync currenciesSync = new CurrenciesSync() {
        @Override
        public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies) {
           // your code    
        }
    };
    currenciesSync.syncCurrencies();
```

This declaration `CurrenciesSync currenciesSync;` creates a `null` `CurrenciesSync` object.

Comment: You mean in activity when I want to pass the List of objects? but it gives me error `'syncCurrencies(List<String>)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.x.x.Interfaces.CurrenciesSync' clashes with 'syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel>)' in 'com.x.x.Interfaces.CurrenciesSync'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`

Comment: `currenciesSync` is `null` so `currenciesSync.syncCurrencies(currencies);` throws the exception. Use the code I posted in my answer, with your implementation of `syncCurrencies`.

Comment: When I try to replace `currenciesSync.syncCurrencies(currencies);` with your code I get the error in previous comment

Comment: Remove also the `CurrenciesSync currenciesSync;` declaration, I also made an edit to my answer change List<String> to List<CurrencyModel>

Comment: You must also remove the previous code of `public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies) {}`

Comment: Thank you so much my problem solved but I have another problem now! the interface method is not being executed in Fragment!

Comment: You can call `currenciesSync.syncCurrencies();` in the same scope where you declared `CurrenciesSync currenciesSync = new CurrenciesSync()`

Comment: I already did that but in destination (a Fragment)     `@Override
    public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies) {
//codes
    }`  // codes does not run

Comment: Can you post the code, including all declarations?

Comment: yes but where can I post them?!

Comment: If it is a lot of code I suggest to start another question relevant to the new problem

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll start another question